# Codeigniter how to get DB errors using hooks and save in logs table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to save all PHP and Database errors in log table in codeigniter. For this i am trying to do this using hooks in codeigniter. This is my code.

hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(    
     'class' => 'Db_log',            
     'function' => 'logQueries',    
     'filename' => 'db_log.php',    
     'filepath' => 'hooks'       
 );
```

Codeigniter how to get DB errors using hooks and save in logs table

I have created file db_log.php in hooks directory. and this is my code.

```
<?php
class Db_log {
function __construct() {

    }

    function logQueries() {
        $CI = & get_instance();

        $times = $CI->db->query_times;    
         $error = $CI->db->error();
         print_r($error);

        // foreach ($CI->db->queries as $key => $query) 
        // { 
             // $sql = $query . " \n Execution Time:" . $times[$key]; 

        // }

    }
}
```

It's working to show all queries but not working when any error comes related to Database. I had tried  $CI->db->error() also to get the error but it's not working. I need to show custom message if any error come related to Database and need to save a entry in custom log table.

Try with shutdown_function

```
public function setHandler() {
        register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
    }

}

function handleShutdown() {

    print_r(error_get_last());



    if (($error = error_get_last())) {
        die("nnnnnnnnnnnnn");
        ob_start();
            echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($error);
            echo "</pre>";
        $message = ob_get_clean();
        //sendEmail($message);
        ob_start();
        echo '{"status":"error","message":"Internal application error!"}';
        ob_flush();
        exit();
    }
}

hooks.php

$hook['pre_system'][] = array(
'class' => 'PHPFatalError',
'function' => 'setHandler',
'filename' => 'PHPFatalError.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible - its one of the flaws in CI < 4

The problem is in their db driver class - if you take a look at their [display_error()](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L1688) function you'll see everytime a DB Error occurs the entire application will be stopped immediately.

However you can try to register a [shutdown function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function) and try to handle some stuff there.

Another method would be to extend the DB Driver - for that purpose you've to extend the Loader.

Comment: I have tried with shutdown function but it's not showing any error in PHPFatalError.php file and not going in if condition for php error and DB error. added code above